# my questions is about code in GDscript (language programing in godot engine)

Tags: godot, gdscript

sprite (attack) is not working in case :

```
if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_attack"):

   $Sprite.play("attack")
```

but in case:

```
if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_attack"):

$Sprite.play("attack")
```

it's working !!!!

what is the solution code pleas?!! Because I want one click on the keyboard to work of sprite...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `if event.is_action_pressed("ui_attack"):` instead?
I've found that `event` works better than `Input` if I only want one action after a button press and not multiple.

If it still doesn't work, try adding `if event.is_action_released("ui_attack"):` afterwards. You may have to put an additional command afterward to make the code acceptable to the engine, such as `print("Key Released")`. In my case, it never ended up printing anything to console, but it did only give me one action per button press.

I am assuming this is the question you were looking for an answer to. If not, please disregard, I have been awake all night and am prone to confusion.

EDIT: I forgot to add that it must be in a `func _input(event)` function to work properly. I've included a simple example that prints text to the console once per press of the left button. See below:

```
extends Node2D

var text = PrintText()
func PrintText():
    return("Print Text Once")

func _ready():
    pass

func _input(event):
    if event.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
    print(text)
```

(P.S. I only discovered Godot in the last week or so, but have been crash-coursing myself ever since. I love the engine, but if my understanding comes off as "basic", forgive me.)

Comment: As you can see from this example, the "if event.is_action_released" was not necessary for this example, however it may useful be in cases in the future, so it's good to have in your back pocket.

Comment: When including code statements use `  ` instead of double quotes ^_^